# I just bought a frame off this kid in my neighborhood but don't know who makes it?

Tags: frames

[image]I bought this frame off a kid in my neighborhood for 100$. I looked like a cool freestyle frame. I built the bike up and just wanted to know if anybody had a clue to what company makes this frame?
this was on bottom bracket case opposite side of serial # GRREA21
thanks for any and all help.
SG

Comment: there are cut outs on each side of the lower seat tube , and there are 2 slots cut out on the front stem tube and there is a slot cut out on the bottom bracket case in between the serial # and this other # i listed?

Comment: [this one](http://www.vitalbmx.com/product/feature/2013-Eastern-Phantom-Complete,2793) looks pretty similar

Answer (score 4):

[This one](http://www.cycleexif.com/eastern-bikes-ti-grim-reaper?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+Cycleexif+%28Cycle+EXIF%29) is the closest I could find. It has similar head tube and seat tube cut outs. It's titanium though. Is yours titanium? This is the [current, steel version](http://easternbikes.com/frames/grim-reaper-8/). As far as I can tell, this frame is identical, with the same brake bosses on the wrong side of the seat stays. Also has cable stops in the same place for the rear brake. Seat tube clamp is under the seat stays as well, which is another uncommon similarity.

If this isn't the same frame, your frame is almost definitely manufactured by [Eastern](http://easternbikes.com/). The cut-outs on the seat tube and head tube are very common on their bikes, and many of their models seem to have a similar brake placement. The frame I linked to is the only one I could find that had the exact same head tube cut-out.  All the rest had a logo cut out of the head tube.

Comment: I'm also fairly sure it's an Eastern. That company has been on a rocky road but they still answer emails and if you email them the serial number I'm pretty sure they'll answer you. A few months ago I had a bad hub and one of the owners sent me the parts I needed.